# VueJs - Passing data to subRoutes component with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I don't understand how to pass data loaded by a 'route Component' to a 'subRoute Component'..
(I'm using Vue.js with Vue-router)

My router looks like that:

```
router.map({
  '/a': {
    component: A,
    subRoutes: {
      '/b': {
        component: B
      },
      '/c': {
        component: C
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I just want to share data loaded by component A with component B and C.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Maybe the `vuex` is what you want: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two simple options.

**The ugly**

Use the [`$parent`](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication) option from the subroute components. That give you access to the parent instance, it's not the recommended way, but it's effective

```js
// from the child component
this.$parent.someData
```

**The good**

Use [props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props). Props give you the chance to pass any data from the parent to a child. It's better, because prevents error (you pass data not an instance) and you pass only what you need, even if it isn't part of the parent data.

```
// parent component
<template>
    <child :childsdata="parentdata"></child>
</template
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                parentdata: 'Hello!'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

// child component
<template>
    {{ childsdata }} <!-- prints "Hello!" -->
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            childsdata: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sending data from `component B` to `component C` is possible using props?

Comment: I found this "<child :childsdata="parentdata"></child>" style answer on many places, but you see under vue-router there is no <child> there is just <router-view> and I would not want to add props to that, as each rout needs a different set of props. This shall be part of the routes object somehow that that vue-router uses.